# why java API prevents us to call add and remove together?

Tags: java, list, collections, listiterator

As per `Java API`-

> IllegalStateException - if neither next nor previous have been called, or remove or add have been called after the last call to next or previous
>
> `remove()`- Removes from the list the last element that was returned by next() or previous() (optional operation). This call can only be made once per call to next or previous. It can be made only if add(E) has not been called after the last call to next or previous.

Since each time when we calling `add` and `remove` together it should remove last element added by `add` why this cause `IllegalStateException`

for example in my code-

- calling each time `next()` before `remove()`
- also `remove()` is not being called twice without calling `next()`

then why there is `java.lang.IllegalStateException` on calling `add` and `remove` together.

My java code is-

```
ListIterator<String> listIterator=list.listIterator();
    while(listIterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(listIterator.next());
        listIterator.add("Intel");
        listIterator.remove();
        //listIterator.remove();
    }
```

after calling `next()` iterator is at next element.

when we are adding element by `add()` iterator moves forward at last element added

then why there is `java.lang.IllegalStateException` on calling `remove()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the wrong documentation: you should read [`ListIterator`'s javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove--).

It says:

> Throws:
>
> ...
>
> IllegalStateException - if neither next nor previous have been called, or **remove or add** have been called after the last call to next or previous

Now, if you want a reason, it's rather simple. You're playing with cursors.

After an `add` or after a `remove`, where is your cursor? You're in a case of incertitude. That's a difficult question to answer, so it's better to show the incertitude by throwing the exception. In order to know it, you have to call `hasNext` or `hasPrevious` which will perform all the calculations again.

Comment: exactly thats my question, what is this `incertitude` state?

Comment: It's when the cursor cannot be placed anywhere because it doesn't know if you want to be before the added element, after the added element or after the initial element. Same for remove, but with less choice. So to remove that incertitude, perform a new call to `hasPrevious`/`hasNext`.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle documentation:

> Removes from the list the last element that was returned by next() or
>   previous() (optional operation). This call can only be made once per
>   call to next or previous. It can be made only if add(E) has not been
>   called after the last call to next or previous.

Answer (score 0):

well, I don't know why it is forbidden, but as you already know, javadoc explicitly forbids that.

however question is why do **you** want to do something like that? Only thing that comes to my mind is that you want to replace current element (i.e. remove and add instead of it). However you can use `set` instead. See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set(E)):

> Replaces the last element returned by next() or previous() with the
>   specified element (optional operation). This call can be made only if
>   neither remove() nor add(E) have been called after the last call to
>   next or previous.

Comment: can you describe in which situation are you "restricted"? what are you unable to achieve? you can call `remove` and `add` if you really need.

Comment: my mean with restriction was not we are unable to achieve any thing, I talking about particular scenario just for curiosity.